# Use push and pop navigation behavior reusing same view(s)

Tags: iphone, ipad, navigationcontroller

I have list of frames. Each frame has context for view(e.g. text frame, image frame) and has specific view for type of frame(viewText, viewImage). Length of list could vary and could be huge. One view is visible at time. User uses gestures to go through frames.

Can I implement navigation logic(pop, push effects) which allows to reuse same view instances for different frames?

Answer (score 0):

You can use UIGestureRecognizers to handle the gestures, and `[UIView + (void)transitionFromView:(UIView *)fromView toView:(UIView *)toView duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration options:(UIViewAnimationOptions)options completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion]` to do he animation. To maintain the stack navigation, just use an NSArray, if you don’t want to mess with UIViewControllers.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but it has 2 possible problems:
1. animation effects don't have push and pop effects;
2. how it will work if two same frames will be in list and transition should be from text view to text view(e.g.: text, image, image, text and so on);

Comment: What do you mean by "push and pop effects"? Sliding to the left and to the right (like UINavigationController) animations are easy with UIView animations.